# A* pathfinding - Slow with huge open maps

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, dijkstra, path-finding

I've implemented A* pathfinding which works flawlessly for smaller grids. However, when the maps become large and no longer maze-structured, such as the map pictured below, the algorithm becomes increasingly slow.

[image: open map]

As per A*'s definition, I'm using an open list and a closed list. The open list is implemented using an `std::set`. The closed list is implemented using Qt's `QSet`.
The `QSet` is Qt's implementation of an `std::unordered_list`.

After profiling my application, I noticed that the re-balancing of the `std::set`'s tree is the most expensive operation. This is noticeable when running the algorithm in two different maps, the one shown below with a large open list size and another maze-like map with a much lower open list size.

In the maze-like map, the size of my open list would fluctuate between 20 and 120 nodes. The open map slowly grew up to more than 2000 nodes.

So my question is if there is any way to reduce the size of the open list?

I have tried the following approaches:

- Change open list to `std::priority_queue`: I was unable to implement this because I need to check the open list to see if it already contains the element. And correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't the priority_queue run into the same issue of re-balancing?
- Use a higher heuristic weight: This didn't solve the problem, the order of magnitude of nodes in the open list was still identical.
- Clipping the nodes in the open list: This resulted in a way faster run-through but often resulted in a path not being found. Initially I thought this would work as I'd only trim the values with a higher F (heuristic + movement) cost which would have become irrelevant. This assumption proved incorrect.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT1:**
Added some code for clarification.

```
std::shared_ptr<Node> Pathfinding::findPath(float heuristicWeight) {
    int i = 0;
    while (!m_sOpen.empty()) {
        ++i;
        std::shared_ptr<Node> current = *m_sOpen.begin();
        m_sOpen.erase(current);
        m_sClosed.insert(*current);
        if (updateNeighbours(current, heuristicWeight)) {
            return std::make_shared<Node>(*m_sClosed.find(*m_nEnd));
        }
        if (i % 100 == 0) {
            qInfo() << "Sizes: " << i << " open_size= " << m_sOpen.size() << " & closed_size= " << m_sClosed.size();
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

bool Pathfinding::updateNeighbours(std::shared_ptr<Node> current, float heuristicWeight) {
    int maxRows = wm.getRows(); // Rows in map
    int maxCols = wm.getCols(); // Cols in map
    for (int x = clamp((current->getX()-1),0,maxCols-1); x <= clamp((current->getX()+1),0,maxCols-1); ++x) {
        for (int y = clamp((current->getY()-1),0,maxRows-1); y <= clamp((current->getY()+1),0,maxRows-1); ++y) {
            bool exists = false;
            Node n = Node(x,y); // Node to compare against and insert if nessecary.
            // Tile contains information about the location in the grid.
            Tile * t = wm.m_tTiles[(x)+(maxCols * y)].get();
            if (t->getValue() != INFINITY) { // Tile is not a wall.
                for (std::set<std::shared_ptr<Node>>::iterator it = m_sOpen.begin(); it != m_sOpen.end(); ++it) {
                    if (**it == n) {
                        exists = true;
                        if ((*it)->getF() > (current->getG() + moveCost(*it,current)) + (*it)->getH()) {
                            (*it)->setG(current->getG() + moveCost(*it,current));
                            (*it)->setParent(current);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
                bool exists_closed = (m_sClosed.find(n) != m_sClosed.end());
                if (!exists && !exists_closed) {
                    std::shared_ptr<Node> sN = std::make_shared<Node>(n);
                    sN->setParent(current);
                    sN->setG(current->getG() + moveCost(sN,current));
                    sN->setH(manhattenCost(sN,m_nEnd)*heuristicWeight);
                    if (sN->getH() == 0) { m_sClosed.insert(*sN); return true; }
                    else m_sOpen.insert(sN);
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Very interesting, could you post some code with your question so we can take a look at your algorithm.  Anything suggested here without code is just theoretical solutions.

Comment: Sure, I'll edit with some code.

Comment: Jump Point Search is better for open spaces. Also, you can use a heap plus a map from coord to index-in-heap for the open list, but it's annoying to code since you have to reimplement the heap.

Comment: Re-balancing the tree at insert and erase is often what eats your execution time in algorithms using std::set and std::map.

Comment: Exactly true, sadly I can't avoid the inserts. I suppose using Jump Point Search to limit the amount of nodes in my set will be the best solution.

Comment: In grid, a good approach is to reduce the number of nodes, as with *way points*, *Navigation meshes* (as [Delaunay_triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation)). Or use some optimization to prune some branches (as for [symmetry-in-pathfinding/](http://aigamedev.com/open/tutorial/symmetry-in-pathfinding/))

Answer (score 0):

Switch from a `std::set` to a `std::priority_queue`.  There is no need to check if a node is already in the open set before adding it to the queue.  It is cheaper to just not insert it in the closed set if it is already there.